# My while loop for jquery, whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys I'm pretty new to coding and was curious if you guys could find any errors with my code that is not working.  Pretty much my goal is to make 293 buttons and have each button say Episode 1, Episode 2 etc.  I obviously don't want to copy and paste 293 html lines and write in the name and link so I decided to make a variable and a while loop inside of jquery however that didn't seem to work I did my research and can't seem to find any answers, I'd appreciate the help

```
<header>
        <img src="/Users/Jared/Downloads/dragon-ball-z-logo-font-background-1.jpg" height="250" width="100%">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id ="panel"class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dragon Ball Episodes</div>
                    <div id ="panelbody"class="panel-body">

                        <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Episode 1</button>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function)(){
    var num =1;
    while(num<293){
        $('#panelbody').append('<button class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Episode</button>')
        num++;
    }
```

Comment: You have both jQuery 1.11.0 and 2.1.1 being loaded - that's a bad idea. You should figure out which one you actually want to be using and only load that one.

Comment: have you had a look at the page source after you think buttons are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help your add `Episode 2`, `Episode 3` .....

```
$(function( $ ){
    var num = 1;
    while(num<293){
        $('#panelbody').append('<button class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Episode ' + (num + 1) + '</button>');
        num++;
    }
});
```

You were quite close; you just did not put the variable `num` to work.

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/e2BB7/)

**A WORD ABOUT THE STRUCTURE OF YOUR PAGE**

1. You do not need to include two versions of jQuery; if you do then just change `$(function() {` to `$(function( $ ) {`.
2. You document does not seem to have a `body` element; I see a `div` right after `</head>`
3. Although you can put your jQuery/JS code and include jQuery core and plugins anywhere in the head or in the body sections, you do not have to put the code where you intend to make changes. Your code can be in the head section or in an included file and it will still alter the DOM appropriately. See the suggested structure below:

> ```
> <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> <script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>     $(function( $ ){
>         var num = 1;
>         while(num<293){
>             $('#panelbody').append('<button class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Episode ' + (num + 1) + '</button>');
>             num++;
>         }
>     });
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div id ="panel"class="panel panel-warning">
>                 <div class="panel-heading">Dragon Ball Episodes</div>
>                     <div id ="panelbody"class="panel-body">
>                         <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Episode 1</button>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <!-- ............ -->
> </body>
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't this `$(function)(){` be `$(function () {`?  Or, in my mind, much more readable: `$(document).ready(function() {`?